# set var session in laravel through ajax call in javascript and get with another call the same var value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

The cache of laravel works for me but is the same values in different browsers.

I'm trying to set a session in laravel, and set session variable through ajax call, then in another ajax call get that session variable.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: url+'setdata',
 data: $('form#data').serialize(),
 dataType: "json",
 processData: false,
 async: false,
 success: function (data) {

  }
});


$.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: url+'getdata,
 data: $('form#data').serialize(),
 dataType: "json",
 processData: false,
 async: false,
 success: function (data) {

  }
});
```

In the first ajax request, I call a function from one controller in laravel. This function performs:

```
Session::put('examplekey', 800);
```

In the second request, the controller function retrieves the session ID:

```
$var = Session::get('examplekey');
return array($var);
```

My problem is, in the second ajax call the session disappears. How can I can set the same session for the same user, in pure php with session_start();

Comment: Hey! Maybe this post will help you find out what's going on: http://sixdayprogrammer.com/2013/11/doing-more-than-one-database-driven-session-mutation-at-a-time-laravel/ Also, please post more of your PHP

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem - have you been able to resolve?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and just found a potential solution:

I found a similar problem relating to laravel 3. For the session to persist in an ajax call you need to return the response correctly.

```
return json_encode($response);
```

This is causing the problem. It's not it appears a valid response to enable the session to persist. Change it to:

```
return Response::json($response);
```

This enables the session to persist!

For some reason a normal form submit or call to the method allows the first one but ajax does not.

I've seen references elsewhere about echo statements in the method affecting the session - the return I suppose must behaving similar to an echo

This is the post that triggered the solution:
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1304

Comment: The link is broken.